# Flutter : InputDecoration suffixIcon position bottom with the line

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
InputDecoration(
    labelText: label,
    floatingLabelBehavior: null,
    hintText: hintText,
    isDense:true,
    suffixIcon: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end:0),
      child: Text("Currency",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
    ),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
  )
```

I trying to align the `Currency` word near the input line, I trying to use Padding but look like not effect

NOTE: because I need it to show even it is unfocus , that why i use suffixIcon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

top height would work

```
  suffixIcon: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 30),
                //...
```

Comment: that is not the standard height, but a minor hack which always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputDecoration(
    labelText: label,
    floatingLabelBehavior: null,
    hintText: hintText,
    isDense:true,
    suffixText: "Currency",
    suffixStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
  )
```

Comment: because i need it to show even it is unfocus , that why i use suffixIcon

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this solves the problem. Thanks.